# How to format the bound value before displaying it when using ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have something like this right now:

```
$scope.value = 0;

///

<input type="number" ng-model="value" placeholder="This is not showing" />
```

This obviously would show a default value of `0` inside my number input, whereas I want the `placeholder` to appear.

How can I do this?

Comment: remove `$scope.value = 0;` from your controller.

Comment: Its simple MVC - if there are no values at all in either controller/model the input will show the placeholder value. else the value initialized gets displayed. @ram1993 is correct :)

Comment: @AbbasKararawala I get that, but the thing is that when I'm inserting this data, I want the default value to be zero. I don't want the default value to be an empty string, or null, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an other variable and if `$scope.value` don't display it.

**Example**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value=0;
  $scope.test = $scope.value == 0 ? '' : $scope.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="test" placeholder="test">  
</div>
```